# Format doubles with General numeric format and pad right with zeros

Tags: c#, string-formatting, tostring, number-formatting

I'm trying to output doubles of various sizes, negative and non-negative, into columns. I would like to use G5 standard numerical format so that it does exponential format when appropriate (i.e. the values are very tiny), but regular formatting otherwise. But I would like the values to be padded with zeros appropriately to line up in columns (i.e. pad zeros on the right normally, and pad zeros before the E in exponentials). Currently, I just have:

```
string.Format("{0}  {1}  {2}", a.ToString("G5"), b.ToString("G5"), c.ToString("G5"));
```

This doesn't work too great since it doesn't pad. I would like my output to look something like this:

```
 1.234000000  0.123400000  1.23450E-03
 4.56780E-08  -1.2345E-09  0.001234000  // negative signs can line up with everything else
-12.34500000  0.045678900 -1.23450E-06  // or line up with each other, whatever is easier, but not both
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Using `:` format like `{0:10}` with the above numbers yields:

```
1.234  0.1234  0.0012345
4.5678E-08  -1.2345E-09  0.001234
-12.345  0.045679  -1.2345E-06
```

Comment: You can use the "," like--> string.Format("{0,10} {1,10....",...)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify padding of string.format using the syntax ",".

Sample would be:

```
string.Format("{0,20} {1,20} {2,20}", a.ToString("G5").PadRight(10, '0'), b.ToString("G5").PadRight(10, '0'), c.ToString("G5").PadRight(10, '0'));
```

or the same with -10.

The numbers after the comma defines the chars of the current block, the PadRight method is used to fill with whatever char you want. ('0' in this case)

Not sure why u want to use "G5", I think this will workout better for you:

```
string.Format("{0} {1,15} {2,15}", a.ToString("E"), b.ToString("E"), c.ToString("E"))
```

Code:

```
double a = 0.00000000000000123;
double b = 0.1231;
double c =12312312;

var ccc = string.Format("{0} {1,15} {2,15}", a.ToString("E"), b.ToString("E"), c.ToString("E"));

//Result --> 1.230000E-015   1.231000E-001   1.231231E+007
```

Comment: That didn't do anything (I tried both 10 and -10). My output using the above numbers was (I'll add to my question for better formatting):

`1.234  0.1234  0.0012345`
    
`4.5678E-08  -1.2345E-09  0.001234`
 
`-12.345  0.045679  -1.2345E-06`

Comment: Won't that pad 0s after an exponential, i.e. `...E-0300` ?

Comment: Yes it will... why not use "E" instead?

Comment: Because I'd prefer 12.345 to 1.2345E+01 and .12345 to 1.2345E-01. And even if I used E, how would I pad 0s before the E?